# azure ad ldapsearch invalid credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, ldap

I am unable to do secure ldap search, to an azure ad instance

requirement: do ldapsearch over internet using ldaps protocol, and get info from Azure ad

my setup

1. azure in eval mode - domain name is the default option presented during creation, eg devopoutlook.onmicrosoft.com
2. created azure ad domain service - domain here is of the format xyz.abc.com (not a routable DNS)
3. Secure LDAP enabled with self signed certificate
4. added rules for incoming ldaps requests, noted down the public ip
5. created a user account, added to global administrator / AAD DC Administrators
6. reset the user's password - verified login works through portal.azure.com

when i attempt a ldapsearch to the public ip from my computer i see the below error

```
LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never  ldapsearch -x -D "userx@devopoutlook.onmicrosoft.com" -W -H ldaps://x.x.x.x:636 -b "dc=devopoutlook,dc=onmicrosoft,dc=com"
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09044E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
```

packet capture shows an encrypted alert from client to server, after client handshake is done, hence i dont think its a cert related issue, i am unable to figure out if its a password issue, i am sure the password is correct

the user account is a cloud only account, so password hash sync should have happened after password reset (i have reset multiple times)

I have also done the same experiment with a onprem ad user, synced via AD connect. that gives the same error

Are there any steps i am missing, or am i expecting something that wouldn't work, please help

Answer (score 0):

**`LdapErr: DSID-0C09044E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580`**

On Workaround try with these

**1)** As you mentioned you using the **Cloud only account**

Cloud only account on an AAD tenant, you need to change the password on the account on the cloud account and wait ~30 minutes or so for the password to replicate before you can bind on AAD DS.  change the password for that user before you can authenticate with LDAP. T**hat is because AAD will not create the password hashes (it needs for NTLM and Kerberos authentication for LDAP) automatically for cloud-only users - but it creates them the next time the password is changed.**

This topic is covered in the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance

**2)**  **The DN name for the user should be similar to how they are named in local Active directory**

For example if I have named my AAD domain services instance domain as contoso.com , then the Domain container values for DN attribute would correspond to that just as in Local AD . Generally all the synced users to AAD domain services go to the container "AADDC Users" within Domain services instance so for a user in domain services it will be

`CN=<firstName lastName>,OU=AADDC Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com`

For more details refer this [document](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54c98f9b-b79b-4c9a-a936-9f4fdcccedab/binding-to-aad-via-ldaps-ends-up-with-quot49-invalid-credentialsquot?forum=WindowsAzureAD):

**3)** **Above error Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid.**

Please verify that your given password is correct or not.
[Reference](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors):

For more details refer this document:   [Tutorial - Configure LDAPS for Azure Active Directory Domain Services | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-configure-ldaps)

Comment: thanks for your response. 

1. yes i have waited 30+ mins, i learnt about the sync etc.. btw do you know how i can verify if sync has happened or not? at the moment i am assuming if i am able to login to portal sync is successful
2. "CN=<firstName lastName>,OU=AADDC Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com" i tried in bind dn format, but i didnt use the OU, thanks a lot, you have given me something i can try
3. yes, i learnt about this too... but we are absolutely sure password is right :-(

Comment: using AADDC Users OU didnt help, i ll update if i figure this out, thanks for your help

Comment: deleting the AADDS and redeploying as user forest did the trick

from what i understand, resource forest => there is no sync of user id between AAD and AADDS

Answer (score 0):

deleting the AADDS and redeploying as user forest did the trick from what i understand, resource forest => there is no sync of user id between AAD and AADDS